# how to find same website is opened more than two times using localStorage / cookies

Tags: javascript, session-state

I want know whether the user has opened the website two / more tabs of the same window. If the user does so, I want to uniquely identify each website.

Comment: Can you explain your question with a better example ?

Comment: say 'example.com' is website and this website is opened in 3 tabs of the same browsing window and while tracking their session I want  uniquely identify each of the three tabs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a cookie that stores a token with a random value each time the web page is loaded.
2. Every few seconds, submit an XMLHttpRequest to your server and include that token, along with the session value of the user.
3. When your server receives this request, write it to a database that keeps track of the last time that token was submitted. At the same time, check to see if the user had submitted any other requests with a different token within the past 10 or so seconds. If yes, then you know they multiple tabs open.

This is a rough answer and you'll have to implement some processes of your own to clean up the tokens, etc, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could work if you only need the info on the browser side.

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e){
   var count = window.localStorage.getItem('num_windows');
   if(count != null) {
      count = parseInt(count) - 1;
      window.localStorage.setItem('num_windows', count);
   }
}, false);

var count = window.localStorage.getItem('num_windows');
if(count == null) {
  window.localStorage.setItem('num_windows', 1);
} else {
  window.localStorage.setItem('num_windows', parseInt(count) + 1);
}
```